# How can I correctly implement 'load more' button in react

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I have this code and it gives out 12 objects that I map

```
class PokemonList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pokemonList: [],
            apiTemplateUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset={number}&limit=12"
        }
        this.loadMore()        
    }

    loadMore=()=>{
        let num = 0;
        let apiTemplateUrl = this.state.apiTemplateUrl;
        let apiUrl = apiTemplateUrl.replace("{number}",num)
            fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=12')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((listPokemons) => {
                listPokemons.results.forEach((aboutPokemon) => {
                    let aboutPokemonUrl = aboutPokemon.url;
                    fetch(aboutPokemonUrl)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((pokeData) => {
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            pokemonList: [...prevState.pokemonList, pokeData]
                          }))
                    })
                 })
            })
        }
```

Component with load more button

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="load-more">
                <button onClick={()=>this.props.loadMore()}>Load More</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

in order for me to give the next 12 I need to replace 0 with 12 here and change fetch
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=12

But how can I do this right
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your offset in the state.  Then update the offset after the fetch.

First add the offset to your state

```
this.state = {
      pokemonList: [],
      offset: 0,
    };
```

Then you can fetch using that offset.

```
fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${this.state.offset}&limit=12`)
```

Then you can update the state how you choose (after your second then?).

```
.then(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          offset: prevState.offset + 12,
        }));
      })
```

Also, you don't need to run this.loadMore() in your constructor.  You can run it in componentWillMount().

The api also returns the next value, so maybe you want to store that instead (listPokemons.next)...

Answer (score 0):

Use JSX like this to render elements from state:

```
render() {
    const pokes = this.state.pokemonList
    return (
        <div className="load-more">
            <button onClick={()=>this.props.loadMore()}>Load More</button>
           {
               pokes.map(poke => {
                   return (<div>{poke.name}</div>)
               }
           }
        </div>
    );
}
```